# Spark DataFrame performance vs SQL server

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset in a SQL Server database that is around 3m rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.vw_MacroRisk

-----------
3268136

SELECT BusinessDate, COUNT(BusinessDate) FROM dbo.vw_MacroRisk GROUP BY BusinessDate
BusinessDate            
----------------------- -----------
2015-04-01 00:00:00.000 3709
<snip another 1101 rows>
```

Together the above queries run in around 5 sec.

I have tried loading this into a spark cluster with the following specs

- Alive Workers: 8
- Cores in use: 144 Total, 0
- Used Memory in use: 982.2
  GB Total, 0.0 B Used

using the following python

```
#get a pandas dataframe of all records in dbo.vw_MacroRisk
positionsDf = load_all_positions(connStr, start, end)
#this is just a regular pandas dataframe, not distributed on spark
```

which doesn't take that long, then...

```
#create a spark dataframe
dPositionsDF = sqlSC.createDataFrame(positionsDf)
dPositionsDF.registerTempTable("Positions")
x = sqlSC.sql("SELECT count(*) as CT from Positions")
print(x.collect()
```

But after 30 sec I gave up waiting for the result. Is this expected? Is there some secret sauce that makes this fly?

Thanks!

Comment: 30 seconds does seem like a very long time for this. My standard test setup is 6 CPU cores total -- 2 for the driver, 4 for executors. I do `df.groupBy($"uid").count().collect` on a 7m row table and get the results in maybe 1 second.

Comment: Is that running in local mode? Does it make a difference if its running on a cluster?

Comment: Well, you're using the most inefficient way to load the data so it at least partially explains performance issues. But since it is not clear how much data do you load or what is actual running time it is hard to say more.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you should consider setting some configurations like partitionColumn, upperBound, lowerBound, and numofPartitions.

For small data and local deployments, you can also get a perf improvement by changing this configuration parameter: spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=4 which is 200 by default.

Here's the detailed answer of a similar question below:

[why spark still slow than mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45366310/why-spark-still-slow-than-mysql?answertab=active#tab-top)

Hope this helps